# Why does the floor not have a texture?

Tags: texturing

I put in a texture diffuse and normal texture image for my floor but it doesn't work. It has the texture correct in the preview but it doesn't show in the render?I would appreciate some help.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a texture on an object, you first must unwrap the object. In *Edit Mode*, select the entire object and then press <kbd>U</kbd>.

From there, there are many options. For a simple plane, I recommend going to top view and pressing project from view.

[image]

If you're unhappy with the size of the texture, go into the image editor, select your entire object in edit mode, and scale it up or down.

[image]